# computably defined function with non computable range

Tags: computability

Are there examples of functions that can be defined computably, though the existence of their range is not computable?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a bit unclear, but you're probably looking for this example:
$$
A(x,n) =
\begin{cases}
x & \text{ if program $x$ halts within $n$ steps}, \\
\bot & \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
This is a computable function whose image is the set of halting problems (together with $\bot$).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're asking:

> Is the range of a computable function necessarily computable?

(The phrase "the existence of" is throwing me off a bit.)

If so, the answer is **no**. The intuitive explanation of why we should expect it to be negative is that in order to tell whether $a$ is in the range of $f$, we seem to have to do an infinite search *(does $f(0)=a$? does $f(1)=a$? does $f(2)=a$? ... and this is even worse if $f$ is not total, in which case asking whether $f(0)=a$ itself requires an infinite search in case $f(0)$ doesn't hatl!)* in case $a\not\in ran(f)$. This doesn't prove that the answer is negative, but it definitely suggests it.

A set $X$ which is the range of a partial computable function is called **computably enumerable** (or c.e. - also "recursively enumerable" and "r.e."). This is equivalent to being the domain of a partial computable function, and - as long as $X$ is nonempty - to being the range of a total computable function. *(These are good exercises. Incidentally, the analogues of these facts can fail in generalized computability theory.)* It turns out that there are **lots** of different kinds of c.e. sets.

- The Halting Problem $K$ - the set of all pairs $(e, n)$ such that the $e$th Turing machine halts on input $n$ *(this is slightly wrong - usually $K$ is defined as the set of $e$ such that $\Phi_e$ halts on input $e$ - this doesn't change anything, and the definition I've given is slightly easier to work with)* - is the most famous example of a c.e. set. It is *maximally complicated* amongst the c.e. sets: if $X$ is c.e., then $X$ is [Turing reducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) (even [$1$-reducible - that is, injectively many-one reducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction#Stronger_reductions)) to $K$.

The proof that $K$ is not computable is a nice diagonal argument: if $\Phi_e$ were to compute $K$, consider the machine $\Phi_c$ which, on input $(d, n)$, runs $\Phi_e(d,n)$ and $(i)$ halts if the output is "No" and $(ii)$ loops endlessly if the output is "Yes" *(the existence of such a machine follows from the existence of a universal Turing machine)*. Now can $\Phi_c(c, c)$ halt?

- Following this, Post asked whether there were any c.e. sets of "intermediate" complexity. This was answered by Friedberg and Muchnik, who showed in fact that there are c.e. sets of *incomparable* Turing degree. This was the invention of the **priority argument**, which would over time be developed to increasingly extreme levels of complexity (Friedberg-Muchnik is an instance of the *finite injury* type of priority argument; Sacks developed the basic *infinite injury* priority method, and after extensive development Lachlan went one step further with a technique so complicated that it was known for a while as the *monster theorem*).
- Primarily - but not exclusively - via priority arguments, a detailed picture of the c.e. sets has emerged. There are far too many fundamental facts about them to mention here; I'll just point the interested reader to [Soare's text on the subject](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540666813), which also functions as a good introduction to computability theory in general. ([This paper of Soare](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183541465), with the same title, may also be of interest - and is definitely shorter! Note that both book and paper are rather old, and no longer represent the state of the art in the field.)
- Interestingly, although c.e. sets of Turing degree strictly between the computable and that of $K$ are known to exist, no *natural* examples are known (those constructed by priority arguments are quite artificial). There is a general body of heuristic evidence that in fact no natural examples exist at all, but this gets technical very quickly.